# Mixed-Type Generic C# Stack (Linked List Implementation)

Tags: c#, generics, stack

I realize that in most cases, it would be beneficial to have a homogeneous, type-safe stack, but I'm curious if this is possible, as I was asked to create a Stack for an exercise which accepts all types.

So I currently have a generic linked-list Stack class, and I'm wondering if there's any way to make the Node class generic so that the Next node can be of a different type. I know I can make the stack accept all types by just making the all the type parameters `object` instead of using a generic, but I was warned of the performance implications of boxing & unboxing of value types / upcasting all of it's elements to the base object class.

So I went ahead an implemented it as Generic, but was unable to find a solution that allowed different types for each Node. If I wanted to avoid the `object` approach, is there a possible solution? Even if it takes a different approach altogether, it doesn't necessarily have to fit this approach.

I hope this makes sense! At any rate, here's the implementation I currently have. Please let me know what you think.

#### Node.cs

```cs
namespace DataStructures
{
    class Node<T>
    {
        public T Value { get; private set; }
        public Node<T> Next { get; set; }

        public Node(T value)
        {
            Value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

#### Stack.cs

```cs
namespace DataStructures
{
    class Stack<T>
    {
        private Node<T> root;
        public int Size { get; private set; } = 0;

        public Stack()
        {

        }

        public Stack(params T[] values)
        {
            foreach (var value in values)
                Push(value);
        }

        public void Push(T value)
        {
            if (value == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("value", "You cannot push a null value onto the stack");

            var newNode = new Node<T>(value);

            if (root != null)
                newNode.Next = root;

            root = newNode;

            Size++;
        }

        public dynamic Peek()
        {
            if (root == null)
                return null;

            return root.Value;
        }

        public T Pop()
        {
            if (root == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("The stack is empty, nothing to pop");

            Size--;

            var popped = root.Value;
            root = root.Next;
            return popped;
        }

        public bool TryPop(out dynamic popped)
        {
            if (root == null)
            {
                popped = null;
                return false;
            }

            else
            {
                popped = Pop();
                return true;
            }
        }

        public bool IsEmpty() => root == null ? true : false;

        public void Clear()
        {
            root = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can only use generics this way if the types you want to put on your structures share a baseclass or interface (besides object). A lot of it depends if you need to know the type afterwards. Perhaps you shouldn't worry about optimization on beforehand in this case.

Comment: Not a linked list, but perhaps you can get some ideas from the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/stack.cs,c5371bef044c6ab6) of [System.Collections.Generic.Stack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.stack-1?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: You can push different types to the stack if they share a common base type; you will have to declare the stack as ``Stack<CommonBaseType>``. If the types have nothing else in common, your only option is to use ``Stack<object>``.

Comment: @stephanV @dumetrulo this is all consistent with what I thought, thanks. Re: needing to know the type afterwards, I thought it was interesting that when I used object, before implementing it as a generic, and did `var popped = stack.Pop(); Console.WriteLine(popped.GetType());` the compiler still knew the type and did not just say everything was object. I think I was under the impression that value types would be upcast as `object` and would lose their original type unless cast back down to it.